# How do I resolve Call to unknown function: 'env' in a freshly installed Laravel 10.3.3?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have just created a Laravel 10.3.3 app with an intention to make an authentication system with JWT. The problem is before I can even do anything when I open config/app.php or config/auth.php I see numerous places complaining about various functions not known for example, `Use of unknown class: 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade'`, and `Call to unknown function: 'env'`. I have looked for solutions online, such as `composer install`, `composer dump-autoload` and even `composer clear-cache` but they all have not worked. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `composer create-project laravel/laravel` should install laravel in your local without much issue. How did you install on your local? Did it successfully install the first time? If so, when you run php artisan serve, you should be able to access localhost without issues.

Comment: Why did you need to open config/app.php or config/auth.php?

Comment: @Shingo, I am trying to setup JWT-Auth

Comment: Did you mean that you saw these complains in your text editor?

Comment: @shingo Some functions like env() on the auth.php and app.php files as well as other classes in various places are marked unknown as a result I cannot use their respective functions needed to set up JWT authentication.

Comment: So you just saw these errors in the editor? If that's the case, it's because you didn't include the folder `lavarel/framework` in your project.

Comment: I don't get you @shingo. I installed my program like `composer create-project laravel/laravel my-project`. I don't expect to add `lavarel/framework` anywhere. Or tell me am I missing something?

Comment: How does your php analyzer know where to find these functions? Does it understand projects created by composer?

Comment: If you are referring to `vendor/laravel/framework`, the folder is there.

Comment: You know what, ignoring these errors and running the code like that has run the auth in jwt just well.

Comment: I know, I have asked twice if these errors only appear in your editor/IDE. And I also know the folder is there. The problem is if you don't include the folder in the project, does your analyzer/IDE know how to find it? Such as include path configurations? If not, then you should include it.